# Como se lê o nome Félix: 'Féliks' ou 'Féliz'?

Tags: pronúncia

Com a ascensão do Jogador João Félix, tenho ouvido as duas pronúncias principalmente na rádio e TV. Os meus amigos criticam fortemente quem pronúncia 'Féliz', muitas vezes gozando.

Como ouvi várias pessoas a dizer dessa maneira, tentei procurar qual a maneira correta de dizer. Quase todos os sítios que encontrei apontam como 'Féliz' a maneira correta de se dizer, no entanto os meus amigos recusam essa maneira porque dizem que não tenho fontes fiáveis (apesar de ter usado inclusive o prontuário da RTP como fonte).

Qual das pronúncias é a correta? Ambas são?

Comment: O [artigo da Wikipedia sobre o jogador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_F%C3%A9lix) também diz que a pronúncia "Féliz" (que se representa [ˈfɛliʃ] no alfabeto fonético international). Mas pronto, a Wikipedia vale o que vale. E nem sei se o artigo se refere ao nome em geral ou ao do jogador em particular (a família dele pode ter a sua tradição própria).

Comment: Nessa [entrevista](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0YL6imshKQ) ouço "Féliks".

Comment: Aprendi que nomes próprios podem ser lidos conforme cada um o deseja. Em PT-BR, se leria Feliks.

Comment: aqui tbm ouço Féliks -> https://www.record.pt/multimedia/videos/detalhe/futre-da-conselhos-a-joao-felix-das-namoradas-aos-pes-ligados?v=pb

Comment: Podes sempre lhe chamar João Mágico :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta questão tem a tendência de voltar à baila de cada vez que aparece um Félix proeminentemente no espaço público (por exemplo Bagão Félix no governo de Durão Barroso e especialmente de Santana Lopes, onde era ministro das Finanças).

A pronúncia tradicional é `[ˈfɛliʃ]`, como atestam todas as fontes.

- [Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/felis-tal-como-quer-e-diz-sempre-bagao-felix/2558), citando [Maria Rocha](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/atualidades/montra/livros/cuidado-com-a-lingua/97):

  > «Quanto a Félix, a grafia latina aconselharia a pronúncia em /ks/, mas esta palavra também entrou no português muito cedo, ainda na fase da formação da língua, aparecendo já no século XI registada como Felici e Felice, sendo, pois, esta a pronúncia que existia e perdurou, mesmo quando se recomeçou a grafar Félix.
  >
  > «Por outro lado, no caso de nomes próprios ou de nomes de família, deve ser respeitada a tradição familiar no que diz respeito à pronúncia de nomes que não seguiram a regra geral na passagem do latim para o português. Assim, se a família pronuncia /félis/ há séculos, essa pronúncia deve ser respeitada.»
- [Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/felix/177), citando o *Vocabulário da Língua Portuguesa* de Rebelo Gonçalves.
- *Guia de uso do português: confrontando regras e usos* de Maria Helena de Moura Neves:

  > A pronúncia tradicionalmente recomendada é com som de **Z** final. ◆ Padre **FÉLIX** parecia observador autorizado da santa Inquisição.

Mais exemplos se podem encontrar. O que também é inegável é que um grande número de pessoas, inclusive por vezes a comunicação social, pronunciam /ks/. Diria que o melhor aqui é usar a pronúncia que a pessoa com o apelido prefere, e em caso de dúvida usar /ʃ/. Em entrevistas a Bagão Félix, ouve-se sempre /ʃ/, presumivelmente porque ele insiste nisso. Exemplos [aqui](https://www.tsf.pt/programa/entrevista-politica/emissao/bagao-felix-nao-ha-tempo-para-medidas-simpaticas-1894069.html) e [aqui](https://www.rtp.pt/noticias/conversa-capital/conversa-capital-com-bagao-felix_a1104584).

Answer (score -1):

Obviamente não há pronúncias à moda do freguês! Não é porque alguém se chama Félix (ou António,  ou....) que pode escolher como pronunciar o seu nome. Em português (inclusive do Brasil) só há uma forma correta: lida como no final de "lápis" e não "cz"!

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, Miguel. Obrigado por contribuir, mas note que, no que se refere a nomes próprios, não se pode dizer que "só há uma forma correta". Especialmente no Brasil (e a pergunta não exclui pt-BR explicitamente), nomes próprios são notoriamente palavras arbitrárias, com pronúncias potencialmente também arbitrárias. Claro que existem pronúncias tradicionais de nomes como Antonio/Antônio/António ou Michael/Maicon, mas pronúncia do nome de um indivíduo específico, para o bem ou para o mal, fica sim "à moda do freguês". :-)